# DIHConfiguration id is a required field in SolrSchema . But not found in DataConfig

Tags: postgresql, solr

When I'm importing data connecting with POSTGRESQl. I'm getting above message in logs.
And also I'm getting logs like missing required field: id. Please sort out this problem. I'm a newbie.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to include your actual DIH configuration file as well (usually named `data-config.xml`, iirc). But according to the error message - you're missing a field named `id` that contains a unique identificator for each document. If the field is named something else in pgsql you can map it over by using `column_name AS id` or using a `<field>` reference in your `data-config.xml` to get the value from `column_name` directly.

Comment: <dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
            driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/inhabitr"
            user="charan"
            password="password"/>
   
  <document>
  <entity name="brand" query="select * from brand">
            <field column="sgid" name="brand_sgid"/>
            <field column="name" name="brand_name"/>
  </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>

Comment: My pk is named as sgid in database. Now is there any problem for solr to identify with that name

Comment: You have to mention the sgid as the unique key in solrs schema.xml file

Comment: Yes I had mentioned.   <uniqueKey>brand_sgid</uniqueKey>

Comment: @MatsLindh Can you please sort out this problem.

Comment: There is no need to a) send me emails on my personal email requesting help b) start pinging me to "sort out a problem". The error message is saying that you have a required field named `id`. That can be set independent of the `uniqueKey` setting. Use the `brand_sgid` value for the `id` field as well; having a field named `id` which is the identifier for the document is a convention you want to follow in either case.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work me when I'm using even field tag id. @MatsLindh

Comment: <entity name="item" pk="sgid" query="select * from item"
        deltaImportQuery="select * from item where sgid='${dih.delta.id}'"
  deltaQuery="select sgid from item where last_modified &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'">
            <id column="sgid" name="sgid"/>
            <field column="name" name="item_name"/>   
   <field column="display_name" name="item_display_name"/>
   <field column="brand_sgid" name="brand_sgid"/>
   <field column="source_url" name="source_url"/>
   <field column="description" name="description"/>
   </entity>

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting relevant information in comments. You're using a tag named `id` - and you're still referring to the name `sgid`. You'd want something like `<field column="sgid" name="id">` - but now you're referring to `sgid` - previously you referred to `brand_sgid` as the uniqueKey. Make sure to use the correct column as your `id`.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh <field column="sgid" name="id"> ... Thanka alot.. As DIH unable to load field named id with another name

Comment: But see   <uniqueKey>sgid</uniqueKey> is named as sgid and I changed in data.config as above u said. still it's working. HOW?